# Laravel Excel export removed last 0 from float number

Tags: laravel, export, maatwebsite-excel

I have below values in my database. When I am exporting the same it removes last 0. So 1.10 display as 1.1.

I tried formatting using FORMAT_NUMBER_00 but it adds 0 at the last even not required.

[It should display 1.10 instead of 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJdR.png)

Comment: use `number_format("1.10",1)` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Not working, I want to display 1.10 including 0 in exported excel.

Comment: ohh then use `number_format("1.10",2);` this

Comment: @KamleshPaul it will convert "1.1" value to "1.10" and it should not be. After exporting to excel it removes last 0 if we use PHP function. In code it is working well, problem while it is exported.

Comment: which library your using post that as well and you export code as well

Comment: if you are using maatwebsite/excel then you can use map method to reformat your column value.

Answer (score 0):

```
You means your number is $num = 012345678;
and you are trying to export CSV file its exports 12345678  right..?
so now you can use this method
$num = 0123456789;
foreach($listings as $listing){
   'number'  =>  '="'.str_replace('"', '\"', $num).'"',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution and posting here to help someone else.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomValueBinder;
use \PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\StringValueBinder

class QuestionnaireExport extends StringValueBinder implements FromCollection, WithCustomValueBinder
```

It does a trick & export excel in original format without removing 0's at last.